# Why is my function changing boolean value to 'on'?

Tags: php, function

So I'm new to php/the programming world and I'm studying online and other forms and such but I couldn't find anything to help answer my question which is why I'm here. Any help is certainly appreciated, Thanks!

I want to turn the below code into a function that I can call. It works just as it stands below as in it outputs a 1 if I check my check box in my form and remains 0 if I don't touch my checkbox.

```
$activeMain = (isset($_POST['activateBox'])) ? $_POST['activateBox'] : false;

if ($activeMain == true) {
    $activeMain = '1';
}
```

However when I try to use a function to do the same thing, and I select my checkbox to display a '1', it remains 0 and if I do a var_dump the output is now "on" instead of 1 like how it is supposed to be.

Below is the function I tried:

```
function activeCheck($activeMain) {

$activeMain = (isset($_POST['activateBox'])) ? $_POST['activateBox'] : false;

    if ($activeMain == true) {
        $activeMain = '1';
    } 

    return $activeMain;//I messed around with a return value
                           and as far as I can tell, it has no effect.

}//ends activeCheck function

activeCheck($activeMain);//call to function
```

In all I'm confused on why it shows "on" when I try to use a function as well as how to get it to work.

EDIT:

How do I turn my original code (first bit of code posted above) into a function?
What values should I use / can I use something else besides _SESSION to check if user has selected the checkbox from the form?

I have a HTML/PHP form in which I give the option to select a checkbox. If users hit the checkbox, the input they provided will output a '1' for a true value.

My HTML/PHP form:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>PHP FORM</title>
    </head>

    <body>
<form method="post" action="processForm.php">

    Name: <input type="text" name="names" required = "required"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Create Users" onclick="formNAMES"><br>

        Activate: <input type="checkbox" name="activateBox">
<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION ['error'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
}


/* Above if statement checks if $_SESSION variable has been set in processForm page. If it has, 
an error message corresponding to the error shows up on redirect to this form. The unset makes sure 
the $_SESSION is destroyed upon completion of the process. */

?>
</form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where do you see `on`? I don't see any `echo`

Comment: @u_mulder it has "on" most likely because they have no value set for them. PHP defaults to that when no `value="xxx"` is given.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know that, that's why I try to understand what is wrong with the code. Maybe OP echoes var and thinks that var in a function is the same as outside it.

Comment: ["active"]=>
  string(2) "on"
}

Comment: What is `active`? You check for `activateBox`. Sure you understand what you do?

Comment: I do understand, otherwise I wouldn't be able to get it to work if I wasn't to use a function.

Comment: Got it, So I understand now that the scope of my function isn't global and defining a global value isn't good. I also get that using _POST as an argument cannot be done. Could you help me with how to fix it or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Change related line to following: The problem is when activateBox is not empty it assings itself to $activeMain naturally.

```
$activeMain = isset($_POST['activateBox']);
```

Updated : Check this one.

```
function activeCheck() {
    return isset($_POST['activateBox']);
}

activeCheck();
```

**Updated Answer Due To Updated Question :**
I removed `session_destory` if you execute that and if you have another session variable ex: `user isLoggedIn` it would be destroyed too. `unset` is OK for the purpose. Please check XSS, Sql injection attacks around the internet implement logic according to best practises, and validate/sanitize your data before process parameters into DB or etc.

```
<?php
// formView.php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>PHP FORM</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="processForm.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="names" required = "required"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Users" onclick="formNAMES"><br>
    Activate: <input type="checkbox" name="activateBox">
    <?php

    if (isset($_SESSION ['error'])) {
            foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $value) {
                echo $value;
            }
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }


    /* Above if statement checks if $_SESSION variable has been set in processForm page. If it has, 
    an error message corresponding to the error shows up on redirect to this form. The unset makes sure 
    the $_SESSION is destroyed upon completion of the process. */

    ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_clean(); ?>


<?php
// processForm.php

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $safeParameters = [];
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        // sanitize your inputs. @see XSS, SQL injection etc.
        // validate parameters according to your needs.
        $safeParameters[$key] = $val;
    }
    $_POST = [];
    checkIsActivated($safeParameters);
    // implement other logic,
    // save form to database etc.
}

function checkIsActivated($parameters)
{
    return !empty($parameters['activateBox']);
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest  remove     `if ($activeMain == true) {
        $activeMain = '1';
    } ` that line you no need to that.

Comment: It cannot. return variable is boolean http://php.net/manual/tr/function.isset.php check this out. If you cannot obtain your desired value you may using wrongly, could you please share your full logic.

Comment: I see, you are giving a parameter to function but you are checking via $_POST global. It may conflicting.

Comment: Got it, So I understand now that the scope of my function isn't global and defining a global value isn't good. I also get that using _POST as an argument cannot be done. Could you help me with how to fix it or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Alei $_POST is a super global please check this out . http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php  You can use super globals in functions or anywhere else it is not affected by scopes, so don't pass to the function just use it in your function. But if you want to make a good design just sanitize and assign your globals to variables at the begining of your script, and use these variables inside your script then you may pass those variables to functions for more readable code. Btw, if you have specific question please share your specific code which/where you struggle.

Comment: We may help you more in that way.